# Magento product custom options to be positioned below the price

Tags: magento, product, block

I would like my Magento product custom options to be positioned below the price. I tried moving the blocks in catalog.xml file but nothing worked.
I did flush all cache every time.

Comment: try to change the phtml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function can be found in

```
/app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

or, if it's not there, look in

```
/app/design/frontend/your_package/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

If the file is not present, then create it by copying from

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

or, if you are on the Enterprise Edition, from:

```
/app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

Remember not to touch anything in the `/app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/
The code responsible for showing prices is:`

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('tierprices') ?>
```

You have to move the code responsible for showing the options, that looks like this:

```
<?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
    <div class="add-to-box">
        <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
    </div>
<?php else:?>
    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions() && $this->getChildChildHtml('container1') ):?>
        <div class="options-container-small">
            <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
    <?php endif;?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

directly below the code that's responsible for prices. Remember that the code above is an example, it may look different in your template, so don't copy-paste it.

Anyway, the file responsible for showing prices is usually     /app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml (with the same fallbacks as usual), but you shouldn't modify it in your case.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done from within the manage product section in admin. Under design, set "Display Product Options In" > "Product Info Column"

Answer (score 0):

You can change them by edit template (.phtml) file:
app/design/frontend/{default}/{default}/catalog/product/view.phtml

Answer (score 0):

Modify the template Or ovverride it in your theme !

/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

```
This is where the price is :

<?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>

This means customer options showing between this if (){}

<?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
```

So you can move them as you like in the template file ! or you can style them with CSS to put them at custom position !